# In python randomly concatenating two arrays until limit length is met

Tags: python

Say i have two arrays:

```
a = [1, 1, 1] and 
b = [0, 0]
```

I want to concatenate these randomly in a seperate variable c, until i reach some desired length of c. So something like:

```
N = 10

c = random_concatenating((a, b), N)

[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Do you have a question? SO isn't a code-writing service; where's your attempt, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: What do you mean "randomly"? In your example you just concatenated them twice (a, b, a, b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A verbose version:

```
import random

a = [1, 1, 1]
b = [0, 0]

N = 10

def random_concatenating(iterable, n):
    rv = []
    l = [*iterable]
    print(l)
    while len(rv) < n:
        rv.extend(random.choice(l))
    return rv[:n]

c = random_concatenating((a, b), N)
print(c)
```

Prints (for example):

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.cycle` to repeat the lists as many times as you need then slice them to the needed list

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, islice
>>> a = [1, 1, 1]
>>> b = [0, 0]
>>> N = 10
>>> list(islice(cycle(a+b), N))
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is one approach. Using `random.choice`

```
import random

a = [1, 1, 1] 
b = [0, 0]
N = 10
foo = a + b

c = []
for i in range(N):
    c.append(random.choice(foo))
print(c)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

*One-line*

```
c = [random.choice(foo) for i in range(N)]
```